# how can I change the value of a text field based on dropdown option in CF7

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a form using Contact Form 7 Wordpress Plugin. I want to automatically assign values to a text field based on user option from a dropdown menu in the same form

I have tried with this form tag and the inline code below, but didn't succeed. Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// On every 'Change' of the drop down with the ID "FavoriteColorDropDown" call the displayTextField function
document.getElementById("FavoriteColorDropDown").addEventListener("change", displayTextField);
  function displayTextField() {
    // Get the value of the selected drop down
    var dropDownText =  document.getElementById("FavoriteColorDropDown").value;
    switch (dropDownText){
    case pink:
       document.getElementById("EnterFavoriteColorLabel").value = "pink";
     break;
    case red:
       document.getElementById("EnterFavoriteColorLabel").value = "red";
     break;
    case purple:
       document.getElementById("EnterFavoriteColorLabel").value = "purple";
     break; 
    }
  }
</script>
```

```html
<label> Your Name (required)
[text* your-name] </label>
 
<label> Your Email (required)
[email* your-email] </label>
 
<label> Your Favorite Color
[select drop-down-menu id:FavoriteColorDropDown "Pink" "Red" "Purple" "Other"] </label>
 
<label id="EnterFavoriteColorLabel"> Please Specify Your Favorite Color
[text favorite-color] </label>
 
[submit "Send"]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Side note: your `displayTextField` func is woefully inefficient. Cache the element returned by the repeated selector or, better still, just use a `switch()` statement rather than all those conditions.

Comment: @Utkanos I just edited the code as instructed. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot imagine how the HTML would be generated, I would suggest first to make sure that the `displayTextField` method gets called. How about changing the way you get the value like this (you may have to change the code depending on the context of your framework which generates the html):

```
document.getElementById("FavoriteColorDropDown").addEventListener("change", displayTextField(this.value))
const displayTextField = val => {
    // Get the value of the selected drop down
    const dropDownText =  val
    // bla bla blah...
  }
```

Also, the code would be less cluttered if you could replace the `if`s with a `switch` as suggested and if the vars were `const`s.